# scikit-learn - explained_variance_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn to build a sample classifier which was trained and tested by an svm. Now i want to analyze the classifier and found the [explained_variance_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score.html) but i don't understand this score. For e.g I get the classification report of the clf and it looks like this...

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.80      0.80      0.80        10
        1.0       0.80      0.80      0.80        10

avg / total       0.80      0.80      0.80        20
```

not bad but the EVS is only `0.2`...sometimes its `-0.X`...so how could this happen? Is it important to have an good EVS? maybe someone could explain me this...

Y_true and Y_pred:

```
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.]

[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
  0.  0.]
```

Comment: Did you try googling "explained variance"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Explained variance is a **regression** metric, this not well defined for the classification problem, there is no point in applying this for such testing. This is a method for validating models like Support Vector Regression, Linear Regression, etc.

Comment: Logistic Regression is a classification model, so explained_variance_score is not appropriate ;)

Comment: Indeed, removed logistic regression from the answer.

Comment: Although its a rather old post, I would add strictly speaking logistic regression is a regression algorithm on its own and not classification. I would refer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification

Answer (score 0):

explained_variance_score, EVS tells you how much variance is explained by your model. The maximum value is one. Higher the EVS better is your model.